# Label and Input fields on the same line

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my HTML form I'm trying to build. It's to build a report to log products we buy from customers.

I'm trying to get these fields on the same line in the center:

- First and Last Name
- ID Type and File Upload
- Customer Item and Checkmend Ref #
- Cosmetic Grade and Cost.

My Code so far is as follows:

```css
    [ FONT ]*/

    @font-face {
      font-family: Oswald-Regular;
      src: url('../fonts/oswald/Oswald-Regular.ttf'); 
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: Oswald-Medium;
      src: url('../fonts/oswald/Oswald-Medium.ttf'); 
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: Oswald-Bold;
      src: url('../fonts/oswald/Oswald-Bold.ttf'); 
    }



    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    [ RESTYLE TAG ]*/

    * {
     margin: 0px; 
     padding: 0px; 
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body, html {
     height: 100%;
     font-family: Oswald-Regular, sans-serif;
    }

    /*---------------------------------------------*/
    a {
     font-family: Oswald-Regular;
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 1.7;
     color: #666666;
     margin: 0px;
     transition: all 0.4s;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    }

    a:focus {
     outline: none !important;
    }

    a:hover {
     text-decoration: none;
      color: #111111;
    }

    /*---------------------------------------------*/
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
     margin: 0px;
    }

    p {
     font-family: Oswald-Regular;
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 1.7;
     color: #666666;
     margin: 0px;
    }

    ul, li {
     margin: 0px;
     list-style-type: none;
    }


    /*---------------------------------------------*/
    input {
     outline: none;
     border: none;
    }

    input[type="number"] {
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
        appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

    input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

    textarea {
      outline: none;
      border: none;
    }

    textarea:focus, input:focus {
      border-color: transparent !important;
    }


    input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #43383e;}
    input:-moz-placeholder { color: #43383e;}
    input::-moz-placeholder { color: #43383e;}
    input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #43383e;}

    textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #43383e;}
    textarea:-moz-placeholder { color: #43383e;}
    textarea::-moz-placeholder { color: #43383e;}
    textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #43383e;}

    /*---------------------------------------------*/
    button {
     outline: none !important;
     border: none;
     background: transparent;
    }

    button:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
    }

    iframe {
     border: none !important;
    }

    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    [ Utility ]*/
    .txt1 {
      font-family: Oswald-Bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #333333;
      line-height: 1.2;
    }

    .txt2 {
      font-family: Oswald-Regular;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #999999;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }

    .txt3 {
      font-family: Oswald-Regular;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #333333;
      line-height: 1.2;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .bg1 {background-color: #3b5998;}
    .bg2 {background-color: #1da1f2;}

    .bo1 {border-bottom: 1px solid #929292;}

    .hov1:hover {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
      color: #111111;
    }

    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    [ login ]*/

    .limiter {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .container-login100 {
      width: 100%;  
      min-height: 100vh;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 15px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #e6e6e6;
    }

    .wrap-login100 {
      width: 320px;
      background: transparent;
      border-radius: 0px;
    }


    /*==================================================================
    [ Form ]*/

    img {
      position:relative;
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .login100-form {
      width: 100%;
      position: center;
    }

    .login100-form-title {
      font-family: Oswald-Medium;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: #43383e;
      line-height: 1.2;
      text-align: center;

      display: block;
    }


    /*------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ Button Login with ]*/

    .btn-login-with {
      font-family: Oswald-Medium;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 1.2;

      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 25px;
    }

    .btn-login-with i {
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .btn-login-with:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #333333;
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ Input ]*/

    .wrap-input100 {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 31px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .input100 {
      font-family: Oswald-Medium;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #43383e;
      line-height: 1.2;

      position: relative;
      display: inline;
      width: 100%;
      height: 62px;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 31px;
      padding: 0 35px 0 35px;
    }


    /*------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ Focus Input ]*/

    .focus-input100 {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      border-radius: 31px;
      background-color: #fff;
      pointer-events: none;
      
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
      transition: all 0.4s;
    }

    .input100:focus + .focus-input100 {
      width: calc(100% + 20px);
    }

    /*---------------------------------------------*/
    .btn-show-pass {
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #aaaaaa;

      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 200;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      padding: 0 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
      -o-transition: background 0.4s;
      -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
      transition: background 0.4s;
    }

    .btn-show-pass:hover {
      color: #111111;
    }

    .btn-show-pass.active {
      color: #111111;
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ Button ]*/
    .container-login100-form-btn {
      width: 100%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .login100-form-btn {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0 20px;
      min-width: 160px;
      height: 62px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border-radius: 31px;

      font-family: Oswald-Regular;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 1.2;
      text-transform: uppercase;

      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
      transition: all 0.4s;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .login100-form-btn::before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      border-radius: 31px;
      background-color: #333333;
      pointer-events: none;
      
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
      transition: all 0.4s;
    }

    .login100-form-btn:hover:before {
      background-color: #222222;
      width: calc(100% + 20px);
    }


    /*------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ Alert validate ]*/
    .alert-validate .btn-show-pass {
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    .validate-input {
      position: relative;
    }

    .alert-validate::before {
      content: attr(data-validate);
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1000;
      max-width: 70%;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #c80000;
      border-radius: 14px;
      padding: 4px 25px 4px 10px;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      right: 10px;
      pointer-events: none;

      font-family: Oswald-Regular;
      color: #c80000;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 1.4;
      text-align: left;

      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;

      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
      -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;
      transition: opacity 0.4s;
    }

    .alert-validate::after {
      content: "\f06a";
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1100;
      color: #c80000;
      font-size: 16px;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      right: 16px;
    }

    .alert-validate:hover:before {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .alert-validate::before {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    [ Responsive ]*/
    @media (max-width: 576px) {
      .wrap-login100 {
        padding-top: 20px
      }
    }
```

```html
<?php

 require_once('auth.php');

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title>Home | Alphabase</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================--> 
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/Linearicons-Free-v1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================--> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================--> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
<p>Test</p>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
 <div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100">
   <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-90 p-b-30">
  <form>
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Customer P.O.</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div>
  <label  for="textinput">First Name</label>  
  <div>
<input class="input100" id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder"  type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div >
  <label  for="texinput">Last Name</label>  
  <div >
 <input class="input100" id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder"  type="text">
  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div >
  <label  for="textarea">Address</label>
  <div >                     
    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea">default text</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div >
  <label  for="textinput">Post Code</label>  
  <div>
  <input class="input100" id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder" type="text">
  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div >
  <label  for="textinput">Contact Number</label>  
  <div >
  <input class="input100" id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder"  type="text">
  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div >
  <label  for="selectbasic">ID Type</label>
  <div >
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic">
      <option value="DriversLicence">Driver's Licence</option>
      <option value="Passport">Passport</option>
      <option value="VISA">VISA</option>
   <option value="Other">Other Government Issued ID</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- File Button --> 
<div >
  <label  for="filebutton">File Button</label>
  <div >
    <input id="ID" name="ID" type="file">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div >
  <label  for="textinput">Customer Item</label>  
  <div >
  <input class="input100" id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder"  type="text">
  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div >
  <label  for="textinput">Checkmend Ref #</label>  
  <div >
  <input class="input100" id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder"  type="text">
  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div >
  <label  for="selectbasic">Cosmetic Grade</label>
  <div >
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="Damaged">For Parts/Repair</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div >
  <label  for="textinput">Cost</label>  
  <div >
  <input class="input100" id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder"  type="text">
  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div >
  <label  for="textarea">Other Notes</label>
  <div >                     
    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>

 </div>
</div>
</div>
 
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
 <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</center>
</html>
</html>
```

And finally, this is what my text fields/fonts look like:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n66f7.png)

I'm new to HTML and CSS programming from scratch.

Comment: So, what you're looking for is the two input fields to be next to eachother instead of below eachother?

Comment: That's right, the ones specified above. Tried using a table method with no luck

Comment: One way to achieve it is using CSS floats. Just go onto any web page which has a form in a similar format to your desired layout, and inspect the elements using your browser tools, then you can see how it's built and styled.

Comment: You have a `<label>` and then following it, a form control (like `<input>` or `<select>` that is wrapped in a `<div>`. Well, a `<div>` is a [_block level_](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) element, which "always starts on a new line". Just starting out, you'll want to learn the differences between _block_, _inline_, _inline-block_ etc, as well as _flex_ (as people have mentioned) and _grid_ layouts. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is a great reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're off to a great start with your formatting. I think the tool you're looking for is flexbox. It's a little complicated, but it turns out to be very powerful and intuitive after a while. Get started at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox and I think you'll have the form layout you're looking for in no time!

One thing I am noticing is that you are using identical `name`s and `id`s on your `input` elements.

As a rule all `id`s in a document must be unique (and you probably don't need them unless you're using JavaScript DOM manipulation).

And `name`s are what's used to identify the data when you submit the form so they should be descriptive of what's in the field. So I'd suggest they match the label, e.g. `name="customer-item"` for "Customer Item".

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap the elements you want to put on the same line with `<div>` tags
2. Give the div tags a class name and flexbox property together
   `display: flex; flex-direction: row;`

Please see my example below - I commented labels out, gave placeholders the right name and also gave margin value to div tags for clean display so you can revert these if you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/terryeah/hqnfv964/

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your input tag and label tag inside the same div tag

```html
<div>
  <label for="input">What ever here</label>
  <input id="input" type="text">
</div>
```

If you wrap the input tag on their own div, it will jump to a new line, since div is block element

```html
      <label for="input">What ever here</label>
<div>
      <input id="input" type="text">
</div>
```

Plus, I see you use the same id for multi input tag. Id must be unique for only one tag. Can't use the same id for many tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use floats for this. A really basic way to do this is by floating both your inputs to the left, which will effectively put them right next to eachother like in my example.

```css
.inputWithLabel {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="inputWithLabel">
    <label for="test1">Test 1</label>
  
    <div>
      <input name="test1"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inputWithLabel">
    <label for="test2">Test 2</label>
  
    <div>
      <input name="test2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use flexboxes for this, and it's much cleaner to do so as it gives more flexibility. However flexboxes are only [fully supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) in modern browsers.

```css
.flex-row {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="inputWithLabel">
    <label for="test1">Test 1</label>
  
    <div>
      <input name="test1"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inputWithLabel">
    <label for="test2">Test 2</label>
  
    <div>
      <input name="test2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```